# Proving solution space for $y'+a_0y=0$ has $\{{e^{-a_{0}t}}\}$ as a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that the solution space for $y'+a_0y=0$ has $\{{e^{-a_{0}t}}\}$ as a basis. (From Friedberg Linear Algebra Thm2.30)

First we can see that ${e^{-a_{0}t}}$ is a solution since 
$y'(t)+a_0y(t)=-a_0e^{-a_0t} +a_0e^{-a_{0}t}=0$
Suppose $x(t)$ is any solution. Then $x'(t)=-a_0x(t)$ for all $t \in R$. 
I do not understand this part. Why is the derivative of $x(t)$ of that form? Is it assumed that all solutions have the form of the basis?

Define $z(t)=e^{a_0t}x(t)$.
I do not understand how they came to this? Why would they make such definition?

$z'(t)=0$ and since $z$ is identically zero, $z$ is a constant function.

Thus, there exists $k \in C$ such that 
$z(t)=e^{a_0t}x(t)=k$ for all $t \in R$.

Therefore $x(t)=ke^{-a_0t}$ ending the proof.

Comment: What do you understand by a solution of the DE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a solution to $y'+a_0 y=0$. Then since $x$ solves the differential equation, it must be that $x'(t)+a_0x(t)=0$ for all $t$, implying that $x'(t)=-a_0x(t)$. Define $z(t)=e^{a_0 t}x(t)$. We choose this definition of $z$ in order to conveniently show that the arbitrary solution $x$ takes the form of the exponential basis function. Differentiating $z$, we find that
\begin{equation*}
z'(t) = e^{a_0 t}x(t) + e^{a_0 t} x'(t),
\end{equation*}
by the product rule. Substituting our form for $x'$, this becomes
\begin{equation*}
z'(t) = a_0e^{a_0 t}x(t) + e^{a_0 t} (-a_0 x(t)) = 0,
\end{equation*}
which holds for all $t$. Therefore, it must be that $z(t) = k$ for some constant $k$. By our definition of $z$, this implies that
\begin{equation*}
z(t) = e^{a_0 t}x(t) = k,
\end{equation*}
which shows that
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = ke^{-a_0 t}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: What exactly is the exponential basis function? It is not discussed in the textbook.

Comment: In this example, the exponential function $e^{-a_0 t}$ is a basis function (eigenfunction) for this differential equation. This simply means that all solutions of the differential equation can be written as a linear combination of the basis functions (and in this case there is only one). Therefore, all solutions take the form $ke^{-a_0 t}$, as we proved.